# In MS Access, using vba; Is there a faster way to get data from a single record recordset than by using ado?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I use adodb recordset to get values from a record in a table. Looks like this is a bit time consuming.
When I know that my sql only returns one row is there any faster methods? Could dlookup be a better alternative? 
An example on how I do it:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE UserId = '" & strUser & "' AND FormId = '" & strForm & "'"
rs.Open strSQL, CurrentProject.Connection

If Not rs.EOF And Not rs.BOF Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    variable1 = rs!Username
    variable2 = rs!Phone
    variable3 = rs!Something
End If
```

Appreciate any tips or hints.

Comment: I would suggest to use a `ForwardOnly` cursor and don't use `*` but only select the fields you really need. Additionally you could try DAO instead of ADO, but I don't think that you feel any difference.

Comment: Man youre life is going to change when you realize there are these sweet domain functions. Its like they were built for this :D look up DLOOKUP

Answer (score 0):

Doug: I do not think that DLookup() would be faster for 3 variables - you need to go for data 3 times.

Comment: Maybe Allen Brownes elookup is the way to go. http://allenbrowne.com/ser-42.html. Faster than dlookup and even possible to retrieve data from more than one field. I'll try.